# MySQL insert into table with values and where

Tags: mysql

I have two tables event and guest and an eventGuest table that joins them together and has some information about the guest (like if they attended etc) and am trying to insert into the eventGuest table without creating a duplicate sort of like:

```
insert into eventGuest(eventID, GuestID, attended) 
    values(iEventID, iGuestID, bAttended) 
where (select count(*) from eventGuest where eventID = iEventID and guestID = iGuestID) = 0
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for sharing. Did it work?

Comment: No, MySQL didn't like the syntax on the where

Comment: Link worked but I needed to alias the columns in the temp table for when the IDs were (coincidentally) the same

Answer (score 0):

Copy one table data to another :-

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE (`col1`,`col2`) SELECT `col1`,`col2` FROM SOURCE_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` if you want to insert values from a table into another:

```
INSERT INTO eventGuest(eventID, GuestID, attended) 
SELECT iEventID, iGuestID, bAttended
FROM Anothertable t
where NOT EXIST(select 1 
                from eventGuest e
                where e.eventID = t.iEventID 
                  and e.guestID = t.iGuestID);
```

Or, if you want to insert into the same table if the values of `eventid` and `iGuestid` doesn't exist, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO eventGuest(eventID, GuestID, attended)
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT 'eventid', 'guestid', 'somevalue' ) AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM eventGuest e
           WHERE e.eventID ='eventid'
           and e.guestID = 'guestid'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do add a unique constraint in the eventGuest table for both eventid and guestid and use INSERT IGNORE or REPLACE command to insert the new data.